# Deriving the Expectation of the conditional distribution for the bivariate lognormal distribution

Tags: conditional-expectation, lognormal-distribution, bivariate

For $(X_1,X_2)$ ~ $Normal(\mu, \Sigma)$:
$$E(X_2|X_1)=\mu_2+\rho*\sigma_2\frac{X_1-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}$$

I am trying to derive the $E(Z_2|Z_1)$ for $(Z_1,Z_2)$~$LogNormal(\mu, \Sigma)$. I guess I could calculate $E(Z_2|Z_1)$ as follows: $$E(Z_2|Z_1)=\int\frac{f_{Z_1,Z_2}}{f_{Z_1}}*Z_2*dZ_2$$ but this seems too complicated. Maybe we can use the relationship between lognormal and normal variables to obtain it in a simpler way? At the end of the day, I am looking to derive this expression so whatever approach is taken will work for me.

The expression for $E(Z_2|Z_1)$ is given [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2334167) in (2.3): $$E(Z_2|Z_1)=exp(\mu_2+\rho*\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}(logZ_1-\mu_1)+0.5*\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2))$$ I am getting something different.

Comment: The conditional distribution of the logarithm is Normal.  Write down its parameters and apply the usual [Lognormal formulas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lognormal+variance+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2).  Since the conditional variance is $\sigma_2^2(1-\rho^2),$ there's nothing to do: your final line is exactly what you will get, without any algebraic simplification at all.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you for the guidance. Which lognormal formulas were you referring to?

Comment: oh ok, found them here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/1-151-probability-and-statistics-in-engineering-spring-2005/9521f25e7e59f284ea67a089187baf56_briefnts8_relnl.pdf Thank you

Comment: The link I gave will send you to many posts here with formulas.  I gave a formula for general moments at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/498328/919.